# Butter and flour vs. Parchment paper

Tags: cake

I am wondering whether it is better to butter and flour cake pans, or to use parchment paper.

I have tried looking it up online and see a lot of information, sometimes conflicting.

One site even says I should butter, parchment, then flour.  But is that necessary?

I've had luck using butter, then a parchment round.  Just wondering what the pros and cons are of each approach.

Comment: I use something that my cake decorating instructor called ‘pan release’. It’s equal parts (by volume) of flour, oil, and shortening.  You can smear on with a paper towel or a pastry brush.  If you have a cake that you know is particularly prone to sticking, then I might put parchment on the bottom but the side I can always release with a small spatula if needed.  (Unless maybe if it’s something like a cheesecake).  I’m not experienced enough to know exactly what the pros and cons are, although parchment can get pricy, and I suspect professionals are more likely to use it for reliability

Answer (score 1):

Parchment paper is fine. Butter and flour is fine. In a pinch, just butter will work almost as well.

Parchment paper tends to be coated with a release agent (look for “non-stick” on the package), so no need for butter on top. Putting butter below parchment paper would be silly (Joe mentioned in a comment that it can help glue the paper down, which makes sense). I’ve never put flour on top of parchment paper, though I guess I can see how it might be off some theoretical help.

Comment: The butter under the parchment is to keep it from sliding around. It acts as a mastic, then releases after heating